# Solace throws Exception when publishing large volume of messages

Tags: solace

Only once in a while I manage to successfully publish a large number of messages with Direct Messaging using JCSMP API to a physical Solace appliance. However, most of the time I am getting the following exception:

```
com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException: Error communicating with the router.
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.sendPubMsgBuffer(TcpClientChannel.java:620)
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.send(TcpClientChannel.java:564)
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.sendMsgOnce(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:1203)
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.sendImpl(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:1023)
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.sendToDestination(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:845)
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.sendToDestination(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:785)
at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.impl.JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.send(JCSMPXMLMessageProducer.java:610)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
   at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1302)
   at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
   at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.smf.SSLSmfClient.doSmfSharedWrite(SSLSmfClient.java:476)
   at com.solacesystems.jcsmp.protocol.impl.TcpClientChannel.sendPubMsgBuffer(TcpClientChannel.java:605)
```

Currently I am trying to publish around 400 messages one by one. I thought it is a network issue but I am connected via LAN cable to Solace appliance.  So, it should not be an issue with network.  Can advise what is wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: For a high-performance Direct publisher sample, try this: https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-java-jcsmp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/solace/samples/jcsmp/patterns/DirectPublisher.java  I got it to > 240k msg/s.

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates that a thread in your application is calling Thread.interrupt() for this sending thread.